# Send CTCP Messages

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm currently working on a project for an introductory class on C#. The idea is to make a basic irc client that connects to a single channel on a single irc server. Most things have been easy to implement, however, I've hit a brick wall when attempting to send CTCP messages.

The format is supposed to be: PRIVMSG target : /U+0001ACTION message/U+0001

I am able to identify these messages as they come in, using the Unicode control character, but whenever I try to send my own "ACTION message" is received.

Here's the code I'm using to send the message:

```
    private TcpClient irc; //declarations of properties of irc class

    private NetworkStream stream;

    private string _inputLine;

    StreamReader reader;

    StreamWriter writer;

    public void Connect() //connects to the irc server in _server on port _port
    {
        irc = new TcpClient(_server, _port);
        stream = irc.GetStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        Send("NICK " + Nick);
        Send("USER " + Nick + " 0 * :" + Nick);


        Listen();
        OnConnect();
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //method is from a windows form
    {

        if (txtMessage.Text.StartsWith("/me"))//sends contents of textbox to SendCTCP if it is an action message
        {
            test.SendCTCP("ACTION " + txtMessage.Text.Remove(0, 3));
            OnAction(test.Nick, txtMessage.Text.Remove(0, 3)); //method OnAction is within the widows form and outputs the message in a textbox for messages sent/received to the channel
        }
        else
        {
            test.SendMessage(txtMessage.Text);
            ChannelTest(test.Nick, txtMessage.Text, null);
        }
        txtMessage.Text = "";
    }

public void SendCTCP(string message) //formats message with /U+0001 characters
{
    char control = '\x01';
    Send("PRIVMSG " + _channel + " : " + control.ToString() + message + control.ToString());
}

    public void Send(string message) //sends message to server using StreamWriter writer
    {
        writer.WriteLine(message);
        writer.Flush();
    }
```

The Send method uses a StreamWriter to send the message to the server.

I've tried with and without the ToString(). I've tried the character itself within the Send block, rather than in control. I've tried every representation of the character I've been able to find, but I've been unable to make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

Sending the test message "/me tests" through the client results, when the server sends it to other clients in the same channel, in the message: IRCTest!IRCTest@mask PRIVMSG #Channel : ACTION  tests

Which is interpreted by every client I can find as: :  ACTION  tests

edit: I've updated the code with, I hope, all the relevant variables and methods

Comment: It is possible your `StreamWriter` uses a different encoding than Unicode.

Comment: _"whenever I try to send my own "ACTION message" is received."_ - your question seems to be missing a few words. Please explain exactly what happens when you send above message. Show the `Send()` implementation. Show how you receive the response and what it contains.

Comment: I've updated the original post with significantly more detail. I hope this makes the situation clearer, and a solution more obvious. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel like an idiot, but at least I figured it out. I've changed it to use '\u0001' as the character, and (wait for it. . .) I deleted the space between the : and the control character. It now functions perfectly.